# chronyc -n sources, which one is S(Status)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, server, ntp

I have a task to school to write from every server S and M. I have read on the internet that M can be: '^*', '^-', '^?', and S can be: '+', '-', '*'. Here is an example of my output:

```
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^* 185.125.190.56                2   6    37    47    +15us[+3645us] +/-   23ms
^- 185.125.190.57                2   6    37    46    +10ms[  +10ms] +/-   25ms
^- 185.125.190.58                2   6    37    45    +13ms[  +13ms] +/-   30ms
^? 91.189.91.157                 0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 2620:2d:4000:1::41            0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 2620:2d:4000:1::3f            0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 2620:2d:4000:1::40            0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^- 213.192.54.227                2   6    37    46    +17ms[  +17ms] +/-   24ms
```

And under MS I see only the M possibilities and not S. Where can I find it?